# Multiple applications on the same kinect device

Tags: c#, .net, kinect

Is is possible to have multiple applications which are using the same kinect device?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Multiple applications can't use same Kinect device as one app can only request one Kinect sensor. You can however choose one of the ways listed below

- Use multiple Kinects so each app uses separate Kinect
- Use single Kinect for one of the app and share data across applications using inter-process communication

Comment: As an addition to the second way, I'd propose moving the Kinect access layer to a separate background process, which serves the data to the clients. The problem with using a Kinect with two applications simultaneously, however, is that the applications won't be able to configure the device freely (for example, switching between default skeleton and seated skeleton, or vertical sensor angle).

Answer (score 1):

Multiple applications cannot share the device itself however using [Kinect Service](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/projects/Kinect-Service) you can build one application that can act as a bridge between two apps sharing the color, skeletal, and depth data. The only thing you won't be able to do out of the box is tilt the Kinect.

Another work around is to have multiple applications or windows tied to one project using a separate Kinect class to provide access to the SDK functions.